# PDO Connection problem "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a project I was working on at school and when I tried to transfer it over to my home computer it was not working. Whenever the website wants to access the PHPMyAdmin database it won't do it and I get this error `"Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\Users\luisa\OneDrive\Escritorio\Luis Web Programming\PHP and Back End\PromotingLocalBusiness\includes\connection.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\luisa\OneDrive\Escritorio\Luis Web Programming\PHP and Back End\PromotingLocalBusiness\includes\connection.php on line 23"`. I have everything set up just like at the school computer but it does not work. This is my connection.php code.

```
<?php
    $type = "mysql";
    $server = "localhost";
    $db = "phpbook-1";
    $port = "3306";
    $charset = "utf8mb4";

    $username = "my username";
    $password = "my password";
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];


    $dsn = "$type:host=$server;dbname=$db;port=$port;charset=$charset";


    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);              
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new PDOException($e -> getMessage(), $e -> getCode());
    }

    $mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $db);
?>
```

And yes, I did create a user account in PHPMyAdmin.

I tried to make multiple accounts and none of them worked. One difference I do see from my home computer is that at school the link to PHPMyAdmin is "localhost:8012/phpmyadmin/" and at home it is "localhost/phpmyadmin/" without the port. I tried using that port at home and every port number XAMPP shows and none of them work.

Comment: It says the driver isn't there. You can check this with: `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`, see: [PDO::getAvailableDrivers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php)

Comment: This question has been answered many times on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpdo%5D+could+not+find+driver